# Bean named - Does Spring in Action has a mistake?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm reading Spring in Action and I notify that maybe this paragraph is not correct:

[image]

"**By default, the bean will be given an ID that is the same as the @Bean-annotated method’s name**" but why "**In this case, the bean will be named *compactDisc***"? I think in this case, bean will be named sgtPeppers.
I'm a fresher in Spring...

**Update:**
I have tried reading the source code that the book provided. And this is:

```
@Configuration
public class CDPlayerConfig {

  @Bean
  public CompactDisc compactDisc() {
    return new SgtPeppers();
  }

  @Bean
  public CDPlayer cdPlayer(CompactDisc compactDisc) {
    return new CDPlayer(compactDisc);
  }

}
```

I think the book have a typo like @ochi said.

Comment: refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Comment: It does seem like a typo in the book, have you tried it? If I had time, i'd try it myself

Comment: @ochi, you're right! I have taken a look in source code of the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read a book and found something does not make sense, first thing you should do is to check the errata.

I believe you are reading 4th Edition of "Spring in Action"

https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition

In Errata:

> ```
> Page 44, Section 2.3.2, third paragraph:
>
> In this case, the bean will be named compactDisc.
>
> should be
>
> In this case, the bean will be named sgtPeppers.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When JavaConfig encounters such a method, it will execute that method and register the return value as a bean within a BeanFactory. @Bean is a method-level annotation and a direct analog of the XML  element.

For comparison sake, the configuration of code  is exactly equivalent to the following Spring XML:

```
<beans>
    <bean name="compactDisc" class="com.acme.compactDisc"/>
</beans>
```

This attribute specifies the bean identifier uniquely. In XMLbased configuration metadata, you use the id and/or name attributes to specify the bean identifier uniquely (**Either through a name or ID**).

For further exploration, kindly consider the given link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-name-generator

Comment: I think your bean line is wrong: the method returns an object of class `CompactDisc`, not of a class `sgtPeppers`

Comment: @ThomasKläger Yeah it will return object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like this part is correct in the book:

> By default, the bean will be given an ID that is the same as the @Bean-annotated method’s name

But it also looks like the book is incorrect in this part:

> In this case, the bean will be named `compactDisc`

I created a quick app where, given the following `psvm`

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);

        // 1)  This bean name will not be found, the method name is sgtPeppers
        CompactDisc compactDisc = ctx.getBean("compactDisc", CompactDisc.class);
        System.out.println("app 1: " + compactDisc.toString());

        // 2) this bean will be found  
        SgtPeppers sgtPeppers = ctx.getBean("sgtPeppers", SgtPeppers.class);
        System.out.println("app 2: " + sgtPeppers.toString());

        CdPlayer cdPlayer = ctx.getBean("cdPlayer", CdPlayer.class);
        System.out.println("app 3: " + cdPlayer.toString());
    }
}
```

And `MyConfig.java` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public CompactDisc sgtPeppers() {
        return new SgtPeppers();
    }

    @Bean
    public CdPlayer cdPlayer(CompactDisc compactDisc) {
        return new CdPlayer(compactDisc);
    }
}
```

will provide you with an exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '**compactDisc**' available

However, if I change the `@Bean-annotated` method's name to `compactDisc` the exception is different.  It reads:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '**sgtPeppers**' available

In short, yes it does look like the book has a mistake... :)